# Replace multiple lines in a file in between pattern in R

Tags: r

Hi I am trying to replace the values between #Table1 and #Table2 with new values available in a vector, the vector is of same length as the number of digits in between two tables (3). Similarly I have to replace the values between #Table2 and #Table3 and #Table3 and #Done.  My file looks like this

```
"#start"
"x"
"y"
"#Table1"
"100"
"123"
"234"
"#Table2"
"3.4"
"9.4"
"#Table3"
"12"
"1"
"#Done"
```

I tried using regular expression using gsub function, to replace the the content between #Table1 and #, but it is not working out for me.

```
new_val=c(1,2,3) #new values which will replace original values
new_file=gsub("(#Table1).*?(#)",as.character(new_val), orig_file)
```

I tried couple of other related functions as well but it seems like they only parse a particular line and not multiple lines. I would be much obliged If anyone can provide some insights on this. Thanks
The output should look like

```
"#start"
"x"
"y"
"#Table1"
"1"
"2"
"3"
"#Table2"
"3.4"
"9.4"
"#Table3"
"12"
"1"
"#Done"
```

Comment: How is this stored in R?  is this a single text line, a vector, list or something else?

Comment: @MelissaKey after importing the file, the file is stored as character (chr [1:100])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since each line is stored seperately, don't use string operations. You just directly need to replace the corresponding values:

```
t_id<-grep('#Table1',orig_file)
new_val<-c(1:3)
nval<-length(new_val)
new_file<-orig_file
new_file[t_id+(1:nval)]<-new_val
```

Optimize as necessary